# Save and display product custom data in emails & orders pages in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, orders

I'm using some code to add custom fields to enable my customers to customize their products.

Here's my current code:

```
/* Add meta fields to all products */
/* SRC: https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/add-custom-data-woocommerce-order-2/ */

/* Step 1: Adding Custom Field for Product */
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button','rs_add_custom_fields');
/**
 * Adds custom field for Product
 * @return [type] [description]
 */
function rs_add_custom_fields()
{

    global $product;

    ob_start();

    ?>

        <div class="wdm-custom-fields">
            <input type="text" placeholder="neutral_bag_count" name="neutral_bag_count">
            <input type="text" placeholder="bright_bag_count" name="bright_bag_count">
            <input type="text" placeholder="pastel_bag_count" name="pastel_bag_count">
            <input type="text" placeholder="reg_tendon_count" name="reg_tendon_count">
            <input type="text" placeholder="gid_tendon_count" name="gid_tendon_count">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

    <?php

    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_flush();

    return $content;
}

/* Step 2: Add Customer Data to WooCommerce Cart */
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data','rs_add_item_data',10,3);

/**
 * Add custom data to Cart
 * @param  [type] $cart_item_data [description]
 * @param  [type] $product_id     [description]
 * @param  [type] $variation_id   [description]
 * @return [type]                 [description]
 */
function rs_add_item_data($cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id)
{
    if(isset($_REQUEST['neutral_bag_count']))
    {
        $cart_item_data['neutral_bag_count'] = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['neutral_bag_count']);
    }

        if(isset($_REQUEST['bright_bag_count']))
    {
        $cart_item_data['bright_bag_count'] = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['bright_bag_count']);
    }

        if(isset($_REQUEST['pastel_bag_count']))
    {
        $cart_item_data['pastel_bag_count'] = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['pastel_bag_count']);
    }

        if(isset($_REQUEST['reg_tendon_count']))
    {
        $cart_item_data['reg_tendon_count'] = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['reg_tendon_count']);
    }

        if(isset($_REQUEST['gid_tendon_count']))
    {
        $cart_item_data['gid_tendon_count'] = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['gid_tendon_count']);
    }

    return $cart_item_data;
}

/* Step 3: Display Details as Meta in Cart */
add_filter('woocommerce_get_item_data','rs_add_item_meta',10,2);

/**
 * Display information as Meta on Cart page
 * @param  [type] $item_data [description]
 * @param  [type] $cart_item [description]
 * @return [type]            [description]
 */
function rs_add_item_meta($item_data, $cart_item)
{

    if(array_key_exists('neutral_bag_count', $cart_item))
    {
        $custom_details = $cart_item['neutral_bag_count'];

        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'   => 'Neutral Bags',
            'value' => $custom_details
        );
    }

    if(array_key_exists('bright_bag_count', $cart_item))
    {
        $custom_details = $cart_item['bright_bag_count'];

        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'   => 'Bright Bags',
            'value' => $custom_details
        );
    }

    if(array_key_exists('pastel_bag_count', $cart_item))
    {
        $custom_details = $cart_item['pastel_bag_count'];

        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'   => 'Pastel Bags',
            'value' => $custom_details
        );
    }

    if(array_key_exists('reg_tendon_count', $cart_item))
    {
        $custom_details = $cart_item['reg_tendon_count'];

        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'   => 'Regular Tendon Sheets',
            'value' => $custom_details
        );
    }

    if(array_key_exists('gid_tendon_count', $cart_item))
    {
        $custom_details = $cart_item['gid_tendon_count'];

        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'   => 'GID Tendon Sheets',
            'value' => $custom_details
        );
    }

    return $item_data;
}

/* Step 4: Add Custom Details as Order Line Items */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'rs_add_custom_order_line_item_meta',10,4 );

function rs_add_custom_order_line_item_meta($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order)
{

    if(array_key_exists('neutral_bag_count', $values))
    {
        $item->add_meta_data('_neutral_bag_count',$values['neutral_bag_count']);
    }

    if(array_key_exists('bright_bag_count', $values))
    {
        $item->add_meta_data('_bright_bag_count',$values['bright_bag_count']);
    }

    if(array_key_exists('pastel_bag_count', $values))
    {
        $item->add_meta_data('_pastel_bag_count',$values['pastel_bag_count']);
    }

    if(array_key_exists('reg_tendon_count', $values))
    {
        $item->add_meta_data('_reg_tendon_count',$values['reg_tendon_count']);
    }

    if(array_key_exists('gid_tendon_count', $values))
    {
        $item->add_meta_data('_gid_tendon_count',$values['gid_tendon_count']);
    }
}
```

Here's how that shows on the single product page:

[image]

Here it is in the cart:

[image]

How do I get the same data to render in my email templates and on the orders page? For clarity, i'm talking about these places:

[image]

[image]

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have revisited all your code and replaced last function by a new one. Now you will get this custom fields displayed for Order items in Order received page, My account > Order view pages, Order edit pages and email notifications…

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_custom_fields_single_product', 20 );
function add_custom_fields_single_product(){
    global $product;
    ?>
        <div class="product-custom-fields">
            <input type="text" placeholder="<?php _e('Neutral Bags', 'woocommerce'); ?>" name="neutral_bag">
            <input type="text" placeholder="<?php _e('Bright Bags', 'woocommerce'); ?>" name="bright_bag">
            <input type="text" placeholder="<?php _e('Pastel Bags', 'woocommerce'); ?>" name="pastel_bag">
            <input type="text" placeholder="<?php _e('Regular Tendon Sheets', 'woocommerce'); ?>" name="reg_tendon">
            <input type="text" placeholder="<?php _e('GID Tendon Sheets', 'woocommerce'); ?>" name="gid_tendon">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_fields_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );
function add_custom_fields_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ){
    if(isset($_POST['neutral_bag']))
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['neutral_bag'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['neutral_bag']);

    if(isset($_POST['bright_bag']))
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['bright_bag'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['bright_bag']);

    if(isset($_POST['pastel_bag']))
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['pastel_bag'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['pastel_bag']);

    if(isset($_POST['reg_tendon']))
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['reg_tendon'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['reg_tendon']);

    if(isset($_POST['gid_tendon']))
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['gid_tendon'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['gid_tendon']);

    $cart_item_data['custom_data']['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() );
    WC()->session->set( 'custom_data', $cart_item_data['custom_data'] );

    return $cart_item_data;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_fields_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );
function display_custom_fields_cart_item_data($item_data, $cart_item){

    if( ! array_key_exists( 'custom_data', $cart_item ) )
        return $item_data;

    if( array_key_exists( 'neutral_bag', $cart_item['custom_data'] ) )
        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'   => __('Neutral Bags', 'woocommerce'),
            'value' => $cart_item['custom_data']['neutral_bag']
        );

    if(array_key_exists('bright_bag', $cart_item['custom_data']))
        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'   => __('Bright Bags', 'woocommerce'),
            'value' => $cart_item['custom_data']['bright_bag']
        );

    if(array_key_exists('pastel_bag', $cart_item['custom_data']))
        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'   => __('Pastel Bags', 'woocommerce'),
            'value' => $cart_item['custom_data']['pastel_bag']
        );

    if(array_key_exists('reg_tendon', $cart_item['custom_data']))
        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'   => __('Regular Tendon Sheets', 'woocommerce'),
            'value' => $cart_item['custom_data']['reg_tendon']
        );

    if(array_key_exists('gid_tendon', $cart_item['custom_data']))
        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'   => __('GID Tendon Sheets', 'woocommerce'),
            'value' => $cart_item['custom_data']['gid_tendon']
        );

    return $item_data;
}

// Save values as Order item data and display them everywhere
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_custom_fields_as_order_item_meta', 20, 4);
function save_custom_fields_as_order_item_meta($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order) {
    if( ! isset($values['custom_data']) )
        return;

    $text_domain ='woocommerce';

    // Save values:

    if( array_key_exists('neutral_bag', $values['custom_data']) ){
        $item->update_meta_data( __('Neutral Bags', $text_domain), $values['custom_data']['neutral_bag'] );
    }

    if( array_key_exists('bright_bag', $values['custom_data'])){
        $item->update_meta_data( __('Bright Bags', $text_domain), $values['custom_data']['bright_bag'] );
    }

    if( array_key_exists('pastel_bag', $values['custom_data'])){
        $item->update_meta_data( __('Pastel Bags', $text_domain), $values['custom_data']['pastel_bag'] );
    }

    if( array_key_exists('reg_tendon', $values['custom_data'])){
        $item->update_meta_data( __('Regular Tendon Sheets', $text_domain), $values['custom_data']['reg_tendon'] );
    }

    if( array_key_exists('gid_tendon', $values['custom_data'])){
        $item->update_meta_data( __('GID Tendon Sheets', $text_domain), $values['custom_data']['gid_tendon'] );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

---

Below Order-received with 4 custom fields filled *(so one empty)*:

[image]

And Backend Order edit page:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, have replaced the add_custom_fields_order_item_meta function but the data isn't showing up- strange..

Comment: @warm__tape As I have revisited all your code you will need **to remove all yours** before and to add all mine… I have retest it, maid a very slight update in my code. For me everything works perfectly. So please try it, **replacing all your code with that new one.**

Comment: oh right sorry, I misread it as you'd only replaced the last function. Thanks- i'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the data into an action hook for the email?

I'm not 100% if this is where you want to place the code in your email, but maybe try something like this:

```
function action_woocommerce_order_item_meta_start( $item_id, $item, $order) { 
   //add your meta values and html here, for example
   $html = 'Pastel Bag Count: '.get_post_meta($order->ID,'_pastel_bag_count',true).'<br />';
}; 

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', 'action_woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', 10, 3 );
```

For more hooks take a look here:
https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-emails/
There are a few more now (this was written in 2016), but Woo's docs may be hard to read.